# Timer on Meta Question

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed that a sizeable portion of meta just a person being pissed off by something that in the end isn't really a big deal. Then they post their whiny question and then get into arguments with people over some truly irrelevant topics. This ends up becoming obnoxious and mods have to waste valuable time cleaning up comments from the ensuing arguments. I'd post examples but I don't necessarily want to call anyone specific out and lets face it there is no challenge in finding your own example.

So here's what I'm suggesting. Once you've finished writing your question it goes on hold for `X` number of minutes to give you time to cool off. Go for a walk, grab a smoke, or just move on with your day. Once the timer is up you can post the question. This will give the user time to decide if the item he/she typed `X` minutes ago is really something that needs to be asked. **"Is this really a problem I need to bring up to meta?"**

Chances are it isn't worth bringing up and OP will probably forget what they were so pissed off about in the first place. Since they didn't post it here was no one to argue with the OP will have no fuel being added to their fire and will probably leave the question in some long lost tab of their browser.

**UPDATE:** 
Two things.

First off this would have to be for certain tags only.

Second I'm kind of half suggesting this in thinking that maybe just in general people cool off and not get so upset about things on SO.

Comment: Isn't that why community review was introduced?

Comment: I can't imagine anything more annoying if I'm trying to post a bug report... and if I'm posting a rant why would I tag it [discussion] if I can get it in instantly by tagging it [bug]?

Comment: **WHY DID YOU NECKBEARD MODERATORS DELAY MY POST**

Comment: Although seriously;  this will just make it less likely the OP is there to make clarifications once the post is actually made

Comment: @RichardTingle I'm saying he would have to choose to still post.

Comment: If you only apply it to certain tags, they'll just remove those tags from the post.  The [meta-tag:bug] tag will just become the new [meta-tag:rant] tag.

Comment: Grab a smoke‽ Grab a lung cancer‽

Comment: @bjb568 i take "fresh-air" breaks. c'mon. be a bit more creative.

Comment: This would be a great april-fools-2015 joke....

Comment: A great april-fools-2015 joke would be blocking the nauseating stream of unicoin questions due to the april-fools-014 joke.

Comment: @bjb568 I'm obviously not advocating meta users smoke cigarettes. It is however a culturally recognized means of stress relief. Essentially whatever you do to calm down. Go do that and then come back to us.

Comment: Is this post supposed to be ironic?

Comment: I can't tell if this is a serious meta question or just a really bad April Fools joke.

Comment: @Mysticial Is either really any better than the other?

Comment: @Zane BUT SMOKING. Ok, whatever.

Comment: @bjb568 maybe you could focus on the idea/message instead of the specifics. If I told you to go smell the roses would you complain that you don't have any roses nearby? You could probably envisioning substituting some other flower, no?

Answer (score 2):

We don't really need a feature/delay for these questions:

### This is what meta's all about.

Comment: whining? so meta is like an AA for the hurt-feelings club??

Comment: @swasheck There's a reason why we have a [Whining Room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/421/whining-room). :P

Comment: @hichris123 Maybe questions should have to pass community review in the whining room before they're allowed on the main site.